# Determine if A is permutation of B using ASCII values

Tags: c++, c++11, permutation

I wrote an function to determine if string `a` is a permutation of string `b`. The definition is as follows:

```
bool isPermutation(std::string a, std::string b){
    if(a.length() != b.length())
        return false;
    int a_sum, b_sum;
    a_sum = b_sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < a.length(); ++i){
        a_sum += a.at(i);
        b_sum += b.at(i);
    }
    return a_sum == b_sum;
}
```

The issue with my approach is that if `a = 600000` and `b = 111111`, the function returns true.

Is there any way I can keep my general approach to this problem (as opposed to sorting the strings then doing `strcmp`) and maintain correctness?

Comment: How can you add up characters in a string?  Shouldnt those be converted into  int's  using a static_cast or something? maybe atoi()?

Comment: @MikeNickaloff thanks for the comment. I'm adding the ASCII values of characters together, and C++ doesn't require that I cast it explicitly. I hope my example of `a = 600000` and `b = 111111` doesn't throw you off, I am talking about their ASCII value as well, not their integer value!

Comment: @ishyfishy  ah ok,  I deleted my answer since it doesn't really apply in that case.

Comment: @MikeNickaloff The problem is not that OP adds characters in the string. The problem is that the algorithm is wrong. Calculating the sum of values in two ranges in no way checkes if one range is a permutation of another or not.

Comment: I Wonder if all answers to this question won't fail if the string holds UTF-8 characters.

Comment: @gaazkam I can extend my program to include UTF-8 characters and get back to you with results tomorrow if you'd like.

Comment: Yes, all answers so far *may* fail on UTF-8 strings. A counterexample is here: http://ideone.com/erfNmC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can count characters separately:

```
bool isPermutation(std::string a, std::string b)
{
    if(a.length() != b.length())
        return false;

    assert(a.length() <= INT_MAX);
    assert(b.length() <= INT_MAX);

    int counts[256] = {};
    for (unsigned char ch : a)
        ++counts[ch];
    for (unsigned char ch : b)
        --counts[ch];
    for (int count : counts)
        if (count)
            return false;

    return true;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I just want to clarify if `counts` is of size 256 because of extended ASCII assumption. Also, why declare `ch` as `unsigned char`?

Comment: @ishyfishy `why declare ch as unsigned char?` `string` holds `char` values, and these can be negative. So if you don't cast them to an unsigned type, AFAIK you might, in theory, risk indexing an array with a negative value when you write `counts[ch]`.

Comment: @JohnZwinck Why not use `string::size_type`?

Comment: @gaazkam I had absolutely no idea char values could be negative! It makes sense now though.

Comment: @gaazkam: Where would I use `string::size_type`?  Instead of `int`?  I find it more intuitive if it's signed.  Plus, cache behavior is better using `int`.  If you expect to have strings over 2 GB in size, use `ssize_t`.

Comment: I wont argue with u. My point was this would save u the assert.

Comment: Although I think it should be noted that this will fail on UTF-8 strings. A counter-example is here: http://ideone.com/erfNmC

Comment: @gaazkam I stand corrected. I misspoke, I have deleted my comment.

Comment: @gaazkam I have opened [a question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36865275/2642059) asking why a hand-spun algorithm would outperform the standard's `is_permutation`.

Answer (score 4):

### A simple approach if you don't need UTF-8 support

The solution to this problem is surprisingly easy. There is a function in standard library handling this.

Assume that `a` and `b` are two `string`s:

```
return is_permutation(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), b.end());
```

Or, if you don't have access to C++14 yet:

```
return a.size() == b.size() && is_permutation(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin());
```

Note though the complexity of this is only guaranteed to be no worse than quadratic in the size of the string. So, if this matters, sorting both strings could indeed be a better solution:

```
string aa(a); sort(aa.begin(), aa.end());
string bb(b); sort(bb.begin(), bb.end());
return (aa == bb);
```

And if this is also to slow, use John Zwinck's answer above, which is linear in complexity.

Link to the documentation for `is_permutation`: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/is_permutation

Link to the documentation for `sort`:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort

### A (little) more complex approach if UTF-8 support is required

The above may fail on UTF-8 strings. The issue here is that UTF-8 is a multibyte character encoding, that is, a single character may be encoded in multiple `char` variables. None of the approaches mentioned above are aware of this, and all assume that a single character is also a sigle `char` variable. An example of two UTF-8 strings were these approaches fail is here: http://ideone.com/erfNmC

The solution may be to temporarily copy our UTF-8 string to a fixed-length UTF-32 encoded string. Assume that `a` and `b` are two UTF-8 encoded `string`s:

```
u32string a32 = wstring_convert<codecvt_utf8<char32_t>, char32_t>{}.from_bytes(a);
u32string b32 = wstring_convert<codecvt_utf8<char32_t>, char32_t>{}.from_bytes(b);
```

Then you can correctly use the aforemented functions on those UTF-32 encoded strings:

```
return is_permutation(a32.begin(), a32.end(), b32.begin(), b32.end()) << '\n';
```

or:

```
sort(a32.begin(), a32.end());
sort(b32.begin(), b32.end());
return (aa == bb);
```

The downside is that now John Zwinck's approach becomes a little bit less practical. You'd have to declare the array for 1114112 elements, as this is how many possible Unicode characters actually exist.

More about conversions to UTF-32: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/wstring_convert/from_bytes

Answer (score 1):

```
std::sort( strOne.begin(), strOne.end() );
std::sort( strTwo.begin(), strTwo.end() );    
return strOne == strTwo;
```

will be sufficient.

---

My suggestion is to use `std::unordered_map`

i.e.

```
std::unordered_map< char, unsigned > umapOne;
std::unordered_map< char, unsigned > umapTwo;
for( char c : strOne ) ++umapOne[c];
for( char c : strTwo ) ++umapTwo[c];
return umapOne == umapTwo;
```

---

As an optimization you can add at the top for a solution

```
if( strOne.size() != strTwo.size() ) return false;
```

---

Better `std::unordered_map` solution,

```
if( strOne.size() != strTwo.size() ) return false; // required
std::unordered_map< char, int > umap;
for( char c : strOne ) ++umap[c];
for( char c : strTwo ) if( --umap[c] < 0 )  return false;
return true;
```

---

If you need to just solve a problem without knowing how to do it, you may use `std::is_permutation`

```
return std::is_permutation( strOne.begin(), strOne.end(), strTwo.begin(), strTwo.end() );
```