# O(N) Identification of Permutations

Tags: c++, big-o, permutation, string-comparison, standard-library

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36818947/2642059) determines if two strings are permutations by comparing their contents. If they contain the same number of each character, they are obviously permutations. This is accomplished in *O(N)* time.

I don't like the answer though because it reinvents what [`is_permutation`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/is_permutation) is designed to do. That said, `is_permutation` has a complexity of:

> At most *O(N<sup>2</sup>)* applications of the predicate, or exactly *N* if the sequences are already equal, where `N=std::distance(first1, last1)`

So I cannot advocate the use of `is_permutation` where it is orders of magnitude slower than a hand-spun algorithm. But surely the implementer of the standard would not miss such an obvious improvement? So why is `is_permutation` *O(N<sup>2</sup>)*?

Comment: Looks like a time/space tradeoff - the faster solution needs an array of counts indexed by the values you're permuting. If those values are bytes, it's an array of 256 entries, as seen in the other answer. If they're something bigger, the array might be unacceptably large.

Comment: Why not sort both first, then compare? In fact, maybe that's what `std:: is_permutation` does? *Nlog(N)* on average, but *N^2* in worst case?

Comment: @Aaron: std::is_permutation can't sort because it does not know how to order elements with respect to each other (because it does not assume that such a thing is meaningful!), it only knows how to test if they are equal.

Comment: @moonshadow Excellent and fascinating comment, up till now I hadn't noticed that `is_permutation` didn't require the less-than operator to be defined.

Comment: "*I cannot advocate the use of is_permutation where it is exponentially slower than a hand-spun algorithm.*" Unless your hand-spun algorithm is O(0), you can rest assured that `is_permutation` **cannot** be exponentially slower.

Comment: @JonathanMee: The giveaway is that Standard Library (STL) algorithms and data structrues which require the less-than operator all have an overload or specialization to take another comparison function.

Comment: @PaulDraper If your hand-spun algorithm is `Θ(log(n))` and `is_permutation` is `Θ(n^2)` then `is_permutation` is exponentially slower.

Comment: @Solomonoff'sSecret, not quite. To say A is X times faster than B means that the time for B divided by the time for A is X. But that's `n^2 / log(n)`, which is not exponential. You would actually need a `O(2^-n)` algorithm in order to be exponentially faster, though of course a sub-constant time algorithm doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @PaulDraper The OP didn't say *X times slower* - the OP said *exponentially slower*. And it's ambiguous whether that expression means as a factor or as a composition. It's common to refer to `log(n)` as exponential speedup over `n`, for example, so I assume the latter interpretation.

Comment: @Solomonoff'sSecret I meant it was *much* slower, but I can see how that was confusing and wrong. I've edited.

Comment: @Solomonoff'sSecret, I must say that I've never heard `O(log n)` being exponentially faster than `O(n)`, e.g. binary search being exponentially faster than linear search, though that interpretation is possible, and self-consistent.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It was I who wrote that answer.

When the string's `value_type` is `char`, the number of elements required in a lookup table is 256.  For a two-byte encoding, 65536.  For a four-byte encoding, the lookup table would have just over 4 billion entries, at a likely size of 16 GB!  And most of it would be unused.

So the first thing is to recognize that even if we restrict the types to `char` and `wchar_t`, it may still be untenable.  Likewise if we want to do `is_permutation` on sequences of type `int`.

We could have a specialization of `std::is_permutation<>` for integral types of size 1 or 2 bytes.  But this is somewhat reminiscent of `std::vector<bool>` which not everyone thinks was a good idea in retrospect.

We could also use a lookup table based on `std::map<T, size_t>`, but this is likely to be allocation-heavy so it might not be a performance win (or at least, not always).  It might be worth implementing one for a detailed comparison though.

In summary, I don't fault the C++ standard for not including a high-performance version of `is_permutation` for `char`.  First because in the real world I'm not sure it's the most common use of the template, and second because the STL is not the be-all and end-all of algorithms, especially where domain knowledge can be used to accelerate computation for special cases.

If it turns out that `is_permutation` for `char` is quite common in the wild, C++ library implementors would be within their rights to provide a specialization for it.

Comment: _"But this is somewhat reminiscent of `std::vector<bool>` which not everyone thinks was a good idea in retrospect."_ I disagree. The reason `std::vector<bool>` was a not a good idea is because it affected memory layout and made `vector<bool>` not a real standard container. `is_permutation<char>` would not have any of these problems, and would be a perfectly fine optimization.

Answer (score 8):

`is_permutation` works on almost any data type. The algorithm in your link works for data types with a small number of values only.

It's the same reason why `std::sort` is O(N log N) but counting sort is O(N).

Comment: I can't buy that, rather than an `int[]` to count characters we could have used a `long long[]` and never needed more space and still run in *O(N)*.

Comment: @JonathanMee How would you know how many buckets to make?  If the array has elements in the range `INT_MIN` to `INT_MAX` then you would need a huge array.

Comment: @doublep Negative the array is `long long[numeric limits<char>::max - numeric_limits<char>::min ]`. That's actually a very small array compared to the performance gain.

Comment: @JonathanMee For a string with type `char` yes.  What about using it on an integer array or a `long long` array?

Comment: @JonathanMee: Even worse, using an array presumes that the data type is integral. But what if your colelction is `std::vector<std::string>` ? I.e. you're not looking for permutations of letters in a word, but words in a sentence? You'd need a `std::map<std::string, int>` to count the occurance of each word, and that map doesn't even have O(1) access to start with.

Comment: @NathanOliver Ah, I get it now. I was thinking just of `char` permutations. Thanks for clarifying for me.

Comment: @MSalters If you're able to use C++11 or higher, `std::unordered_map` has better time complexity for accesses.

Answer (score 4):

The answer you cite works on `char`s. It assumes they are 8 bit (not necessarily the case) and so there are only 256 possibilities for each value, and that you can cheaply go from each value to a numeric index to use for a lookup table of counts (for `char` in this case, the value and the index are the same thing!)

It generates a count of how many times each `char` value occurs in each string; then, if these distributions are the same for both strings, the strings are permutations of each other.

What is the time complexity?

- you have to walk each character of each string, so M+N steps for two inputs of lengths M and N
- each of these steps involves incrementing an count in a fixed size table at an index given by the char, so is constant time

So the overall time complexity is O(N+M): linear, as you describe.

Now, `std::is_permutation` makes no such assumptions about its input. It doesn't know that there are only 256 possibilities, or indeed that they are bounded at all. It doesn't know how to go from an input value to a number it can use as an index, never mind how to do that in constant time. The only thing it knows is how to compare two values for equality, because the caller supplies that information.

So, the time complexity:

- we know it has to consider each element of each input at some point
- we know that, for each element it hasn't seen before (I'll leave discussion of how that's determined and why that doesn't impact the big O complexity as an exercise), it's not able to turn the element into any kind of index or key for a table of counts, so it has no way of counting how many occurrences of that element exist which is better than a linear walk through both inputs to see how many elements match

so the complexity is going to be quadratic at best.

Comment: "quadratic at best". Surely *Nlog(N)* is possible (on average) - sort the ranges first, then compare?

Comment: @Aaron: not with the signature as it is; the BinaryPredicate returns true if its inputs are equal and false otherwise, but to sort, you need to be able to impose an ordering, not just test for equality, so you would need to make the BinaryPredicate able to return (less than/greater than/equal) rather than (equal/not equal), which potentially constrains the sort of values you can work with.

Comment: Certainly, if you're willing to assume more things, you can do better. You could imagine a less general form of is_permutation that takes a function accepting an element and yielding a hash key, which might get you back into average case linear complexity if you stored the counts in a hash table. But that's not what the fully general std::is_permutation does.

Comment: You actually have to compare the two tables as well. Of course, if you may assume `char` has 256 possible values, that's O(256) < O(N). Also, for two strings of length M and N, you can decide in O(1) that they're not permutations if M != N. You only need to count characters if M==N, and then it's obviously just O(N).

Comment: @MSalters: comparing two fixed size tables is constant time.