# Checking if one string is a permutation of another in C++

Tags: c++, string, algorithm

I've been working on some programming questions to try to refresh my memory with data structures and algorithms. The problem is checking to see if one string is a permutation of another.

A lot of code solutions I've seen sorts each string, then checks to see if the sorted strings are equal to each other. This is usually done by doing something like this:

```
sort(strOne.begin(), strOne.end());
sort(strTwo.begin(), strTwo.end());

for (int i = 0; i < strOne.length(); i++) 
    {
        if (strOne[i] != strTwo[i]) 
        {
            return false; 
        }
    }
```

However, I am wondering if after sorting the strings you could just compare the strings directly instead of using the for loop. For example,

```
     if (strOne == strTwo) {
    return true; 
 }
```

Is there something that I'm missing in which the second option would not work? I feel like I am missing a basic concept because it seems like most solutions have the for loop to iterate the string.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `std::is_permutation`. Just use it. Or you can read its code if you want to know how it works.

Comment: [link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/is_permutation) with example....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36818877/determine-if-a-is-permutation-of-b-using-ascii-values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use str1.compare(str2) which will compare the strings lexographically and return 0 if they are equal.

But, your solution is taking O(nlogn) complexity and it can be solved in linear time...

Comment: There's no sound justification for recommending `str1.compare(str2) != 0` over `str1 == str2`; I've only ever seen such a recommendation from programmers of languages lacking operator overloading.  Great point about linear time though: just iterate the first string doing `++freq[s[i]]`, where `freq` can be indexed by character values and defaults to 0, then the second string `--freq[s[i]]`, then check there's no non-zero values.

Comment: (thinking about it a bit more - and assuming you `return false` up front if the string lengths differ, you can use `if (--freq[s[i]] < 0) return false;` for earlier bail-out, and then won't need a final check for non-zeros before `return true`).

Comment: if `str1.compare(str2)` is valid, then `std::set_symmetric_difference` should be valid too http://pastebin.com/2i3quAQJ

Answer (score 2):

Please explicitly return true or false in all possible conditions. Otherwise you may not get desired result.

In first block of code, you have no return value defined outside the for loop.
So, **explicitly your function will return nothing if two strings are equal.**

In second block of code, you have no return value defined outside the if statement.
So, **explicitly your function will return nothing if two strings are not equal.**

Answer (score 1):

```
std::sort( strOne.begin(), strOne.end() );
std::sort( strTwo.begin(), strTwo.end() );    
return strOne == strTwo;
```

will be sufficient.

---

My suggestion is to use `std::unordered_map`

i.e.

```
std::unordered_map< char, unsigned > umapOne;
std::unordered_map< char, unsigned > umapTwo;
for( char c : strOne ) ++umapOne[c];
for( char c : strTwo ) ++umapTwo[c];
return umapOne == umapTwo;
```

---

As an optimization you can add at the top for a solution

```
if( strOne.size() != strTwo.size() ) return false;
```

---

Better `std::unordered_map` solution,

```
if( strOne.size() != strTwo.size() ) return false; // required
std::unordered_map< char, int > umap;
for( char c : strOne ) ++umap[c];
for( char c : strTwo ) if( --umap[c] < 0 )  return false;
return true;
```

---

If you need to just solve a problem without knowing how to do it, you may use `std::is_permutation`

```
return std::is_permutation( strOne.begin(), strOne.end(), strTwo.begin(), strTwo.end() );
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to complement the other answers, if you know a priori the range of the characters of both strings ('a' - 'z') or something similar to that, then you can solve the problem in linear time. It might be ok for this problem to solve it in O(n log n), but that is not always the case.

Here would be my version to solve this problem. It uses the fact that if both words have an equal frequency for every character, then one can be rearranged into the other.

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string a, b;
    cin >> a >> b;
    vector<int> frequencyOfLettersA(26, 0);
    vector<int> frequencyOfLettersB(26, 0);

    for(char c : a)
        frequencyOfLettersA[c - 'a']++;
    for(char c : b)
        frequencyOfLettersB[c - 'a']++; 

    bool isPermutation = true;
    for(int i = 0; i < 26; ++i)
    {
        if(frequencyOfLettersA[i] != frequencyOfLettersB[i])
        {
            isPermutation = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(isPermutation)
        cout << "Yes" << endl;
    else
        cout << "No" << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The STL way is:

```
std::string str0, str1;
bool IsPermutation = std::is_permutation(str0.begin(), str0.end(), str1.begin(), str1.end());
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can directly compare string. A correcct way to use string comparison in your function would be

```
 return str1 == str2;
```

The roundabout way

```
 if (str1 == str2) {
     return true;
 }
 else {
     return false;
 }
```

has major drawbacks: it's several times longer, it's easy to forget the `else` part (you just did), and it's easier to break during refactoring.